# Android: AChartEngine mRenderer.setPanLimits in dates

Tags: java, android, achartengine, linechart

I have line chart, using achartengine library. In x axis there are Dates. I need to set minimal viewable date. How to do that if x axis is made from `Date` objects and setPanLimits takes `double` value?

```
    Date minDate = new GregorianCalendar(2008, 1, 01).getTime();
    Date maxDate = new GregorianCalendar(2008, 1, 30).getTime();
    // mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { minX, maxX, minY, maxY});
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { minX, maxX, 0, 1000});
    mRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { minXe, maxX, 0, 1000 });
```

If I set minimal x axis as 0, then can't move x axis at all, but shows all x values in view. I need to set little bit smaller x for min and little bit bigger x for max, so can move chart a little to left and right

I found about that 3 days is `private static final double THREEDAYS = 81300000 *3;`, but how about conversion from Date to that double, so I can substract to get minX?

I hope you will understand my question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extends viewport to 3 days

```
double THREEDAYS = 81300000 *3;
double minX = minDate.getTime() - THREEDAYS;
double maxX = maxDate.getTime() + THREEDAYS;
```

Hope this will help to others